# Let $\vec r=\vec r_1 + t\vec s_1$ and $\vec r=\vec r_2 + t\vec s_2$ be parametric vector equations for lines $l_1$ and $l_2$.

Tags: geometry

Let $\vec r=\vec r_1 + t\vec s_1$ and $\vec r=\vec r_2 + t\vec s_2$ be parametric vector equations for lines $l_1$ and $l_2$. What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ to be intersecting?

Comment: in both equations cannot be the same parameter $t$!

Comment: That there are $\;t_1,\,t_2\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;\vec r_1+t_1\vec s_1=\vec r_2+t_2\vec s_2\;$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Not "cannot", but rather the parameter may be different in the equations".

Comment: and in your first equation is one $r$ where there cannot be an $r$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the lines are not parallel, i.e. that $s_1\times s_2\neq0$, then we require that the shortest distance between the lines is zero, and this can be written as $$(r_1-r_2)\cdot (s_1\times s_2)=0$$